# Pattern for changing behavior of code if exceptions occur

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I need to implement in C# the following piece of functionality:

We need to check and retrieve updated data from web service regularly - say, every 5 minutes.

If we cannot connect to server once I would like to reschedule to request data in 10 minutes, then if connection fails again it will rescheduled in an hour or inform an administrator. Once connect is successful we roll back to 5 mins requests.

I would like to implement in general way to be reusable for any kind of request that can error. Say it can be calls to db, to services - every kind of those job will have their ID. This piece of code will wrap over those calls. If any exception or bad response received, system should react in an appropriate way - depends on the state of job - and move job to other state. Say if bad response received 1 time we just reschedule request, next time we won't reschedule it but stop the job and inform admin.

I looked at Circuit Breaker pattern, but it's a bit different.

Can you please advise if there is any pattern or code to look at or reuse?

Comment: Use State pattern for the timeout value part, and the two patterns should work fine together

Answer (score 0):

For this the best solution is the state pattern